# Generalising injective modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Free modules over a ring generalise to projective modules over a ring, which generalise to flat modules, which generalise to torsion free modules:
$$
\textrm{free} \to 
\textrm{projective}
\to
\textrm{flat}
\to 
\textrm{torsion free}.
$$
Does there exist an analogous chain of properties for injective modules.

Comment: There is a notion of a [cofree module](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CofreeModule.html) and there's also a notion of a *divisible module* over any type of ring, in the sense that appears in T.Y. Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* around p 70.  The last one always seemed like a fair dual to flatness.   I've forgotten a dual for torsion-free modules, if I knew one. So at least Cofree -> injective -> divisible.